# Procmail deleting body

Tags: procmail

I have a procmail recipe which sends the body of a mail to a script. Works well but procmail then sends the mail without the body to my default folder.

```
:0
* ^Subject.*Telemetry rotate$
{
:0 bf
! `/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/script/script.php`
}
```

How can I have procmail send the body to my script without deleting it or send a copy to a folder and then delete the original.

Comment: Do the backticks work like a command substitution in the procmail config? I can't remember... Why would you want to use a command substitution there?

Comment: As far as I can (also) remember the backticks serves to "escape" the command

Comment: The `!` forwards the mail to the address that the PHP script outputs. That's what the `!` at the start does.  Is this what you intend?  Did you intend to use `|` instead? Check the `promailrc` manual...

Comment: I would regard it as surprising but not necessarily a bug that you can use the `f` flag with an `!` action. This is a corner case I have never seen before. I'm pretty sure the recipe doesn't do at all what you want; but your question really should spell out more explicitly what you do want. The idea that backticks "escape" a command is certainly nonsense.

Comment: yes, I want to pass the body to a script but also want a copy/original to be  passed/sent to a folder for record purposes

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors here. The `f` flag says to replace the message with the output from the filter (though the `b` restricts this action to just the body). The braces are also superfluous here. So I'd go with

```
:0b
* ^Subject.*Telemetry rotate$
! `php -f /path/to/script/script.php`
```

if indeed the plan is to *(1)* pass the body to the PHP script, *(2)* capture the script's output (this is what the `` `backticks` `` do) and *(3)* forward the message to the address captured (that's wat the `!` action does).

If your intention is merely to pass the body to your script, that would be

```
:0b
* ^Subject.*Telemetry rotate$
| php -f /path/to/script/script.php
```

maybe also with a `c` flag if you want to continue to process the message after this point.

You'll notice that I took out the hard-coded path `/usr/bin`; hardcoding the path makes the script less portable, and makes it impossible (or at least extremely cumbersome) to replace `php` with a wrapper for debugging purposes. I'd recommend to simply make sure you set up your `PATH` correctly in production.